# How can retrieve {pushId} with firebase cloud functions?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-admin

I am learning firebase cloud functions. I have a function that looks like that:

```
exports.gameLoopBeing = functions.database.ref('/tables/{pushId}/gamestarted')
    .onWrite(event => {
    //I want to retrieve the pushID        
    console.log(event.data.pushID);

});
```

event.data.pushID clearly doesn't work. How can retrieve the pushID? I looked at the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/save-data) and couldn't find anything.

For those who don't know that pushId is. This function listens to every change done inside elements inside /table. For example:

- in /table/1 the pushId is 1
- in /table/2 the pushId is 2
- in /table/N the pushID is N

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The wildcards in the ref path are provided in the event [params](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/functions.Event#params) object:

```
exports.gameLoopBeing = functions.database.ref('/tables/{pushId}/gamestarted')
    .onWrite(event => {
    //I want to retrieve the pushID        
    console.log(event.params.pushId);

});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
exports.gameLoopBeing = functions.database.ref('/tables/{pushId}/gamestarted')
     .onWrite((change, context) => {
     //I want to retrieve the pushID        
      console.log(context.params.pushId);
    });
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it would be better to include some _context_, explaining _how_ it works and _when_ to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.

Comment: `onWrite()`  which triggers when data is created, updated, or deleted in the firebase Realtime Database.it will respond two parameters, first parameter is a `Change` object that contains two snapshots that represent the data state before and after the triggering event.

`const before = change.before.val();`
`const after = change.after.val();`
For the reference [https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events]